# Accessing Realm property on main thread crashes

Tags: ios, multithreading, realm

I am trying to fetch realm objects and store them in a dictionary with key being a date string.

I start fetching the objects in a realm queue

```
//im doing this as data fetch is taking too much time
dispatch_async( [[ActivityManager sharedInstance]getRealmQueue], ^{
   [self getActivitiesForStartDate:_startDate endDate:_endDate];
 });
```

what getActivitiesForStartDate does is:

1. Get array of dates
2. For each date in the array get the realm objects to show on tableview

   ```
   RLMResults *activityResults = [[[self getActivitySource]activities] objectsWhere:@"my predicate string"];
   ```

   and enumerate through the fetched activities, and add them to an array based on condition

   ```
   for (RealmActivity *tempActivity in tempActArr){
       if (tempActivity.startTime) {
     //condition met
               [dataArr addObject:@{@"activity":tempActivity,
                                    @"occurence":selectedDate}];
       }else{
             [dataArr addObject:@{@"activity":tempActivity,
                                    @"occurence":tempActivity.startTime}];
           }
   }
   ```

after the data fetch is done, I'm trying to load the realm objects on tableview.

However when I try to access Realm object in cellForRow method, it crashes the app saying trying to access Realm from incorrect thread:

```
- (void)configureCell:(TaskListViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   NSArray *ar = self.dataDictionary[[[self.monthView dateSelected]shortDateString]];

    RealmActivity *activity = ar[indexPath.section];
    cell.dateTime.text = activity.Type; <- crashes here
    cell.regarding.text = activity.regarding;
    cell.location.text =activity.location;

}
```

I see that configureCell is getting called on main thread, but how can I use Realm properly to avoid crashes like these ?

I have no idea how to use RLMThreadSafeReference for preparing datasource.

Comment: Remove the relam framework from build phase and drag it to the project bundle then it works.

Comment: how does it affect the crash ?

Comment: can you please try this i got the same issue and issue has been resolved.

Comment: Your RealmActivity class is subclass of RLMObject?

Comment: yes. IT contains the basic properties and RLMArrays!

Comment: Have you try the above solutions related with the fremework